# Why won't these perfect number finding program attempts work?

Tags: java, perfect-numbers

I just started learning about coding yesterday and wanted to attemp making a program to help find all perfect numbers up to a given number today. These won't work. No error messages show up on Eclipse so I guess the mistakes are logical (?) Here are the relevant pieces of code, can someone please tell me where the error is?

```
protected void actionPerformedProcessBtn(ActionEvent arg0) {
    txtS.setText("");
    int limit = Integer.parseInt(txtAmmount.getText()), a = 1, b = 1, c = 0;
    while (a <= limit) {
        while(a > b) {
            if (a % b != 0) {
                b++;
            }
            else {
               c = c + b; 
               b++;
            }
        }
        if (c == a) 
            txtS.append(a + "\n");
        a++;
    }
}

void ActionPerformedDoBtn(ActionEvent arg0) {
    int c = 1, d, e;
    txtS.setText("");
    while (c <= 1000) {
        d = 0;
        e = 0;
        while(d < c) {  
            if(c % d == 0)
                e += d;
            d++;
        }
        if (e == c)
            txtS.append("Perf Num:" + c);
        c++;
    }
}
```

Comment: welcome to SO.  What result do you get?  What result do you expect?

Comment: *I just started learning about coding yesterday* Now it's time to start learning about debugging.

Comment: You need to re-initialise b and c for every different value of a.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13805335/perfect-numbers-something-wrong?rq=1

Comment: Thank you. What's debugging? Thanks, I understand now, fixed it and now it works.

Answer (score 1):

You need to reinitialise b and c for each value of a.

Let's say you were working on a = 9, so you increased b to 8, checked if 9 is divisible by 8, and then increased b to 9 which exited the loop while (a > b). Now you set a to 10. At this point, b is already equal to 9 from the previous iteration. So you check whether 10 is divisible by 9, which it isn't.

int b = 1, c = 0; belongs *inside* the while (a <= limit) loop.